# MVC, can Model have a Controller instance?

Tags: model-view-controller

it's a short question, according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Can I do a MVC implementation where my Model have a Controller instance? I mean something like this:

[image]

The blue arrow means Updates.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems wrong.

Comment: If you do this. Its not MVC. Try to integrate MVC with another pattern.

Comment: In some implementation the controller can observe model for changes, but that's for cases when change in model layer unlocks some functionality in the controller. Though that sort of behaviour is not common in MVC or MVC-inspired patterns and is quite questionable practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe not.

Personally I would put the update method in the model layer, probably in my [DataObjectMapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern), and call it from the controller.

Your models should never talk to the controller, only the other way round.

Comment: Man I was looking what you gave me. Go to "Figure 7-2  Cocoa version of MVC as a compound design pattern" that's what im talking about

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern for update.

Here is good description of MVC(as for me): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html

Comment: Thanks I know about this, that was just a doubt.